# Extra qualifier for member

Tags: c++, class

Adding `lfsr` to the definition of the member function `rsa()` in the following code give extra qualification error when compiling with gcc 2.8.2. While I see that this 'qualifier' is put in examples mentioned in [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/) page, I don't know why g++ doesn't accept it.

Here is the code:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp> 

using namespace std;

class lfsr
{
    int y, xx, polyLoc, turnCount, n, end, p, q, d, f, e, m, c, l, g;
    boost::dynamic_bitset<> inpSeq;
    boost::dynamic_bitset<> operSeq;
    boost::dynamic_bitset<> bit;
    vector<int> xorArray;
    vector<int> keyReg;
public:
    lfsr(int, int, int, int, int, int, int,
         int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int,
         boost::dynamic_bitset<>, boost::dynamic_bitset<>, boost::dynamic_bitset<>);

    void rsa(int, int, int, boost::dynamic_bitset<> = boost::dynamic_bitset<>(5));

    int key()
    {
        while (polyLoc > 0)
        {
            xorArray.push_back(polyLoc % 10);
            polyLoc /= 10;
        }
        sort(xorArray.rbegin(), xorArray.rend());
        operSeq = inpSeq;
        keyReg.push_back(inpSeq[0]);
        int x = xorArray[0];

        do {
            for (unsigned int r = 1; r < xorArray.size(); r++)
            {
                bit[4] = operSeq[x];
                y = xorArray[r];
                bit[4] = bit[4] ^ operSeq[y];
            }
            operSeq >>= 1;
            operSeq[4] = bit[4];
            keyReg.push_back(operSeq[0]);
            turnCount++;
        }

        while ((operSeq != inpSeq) && (turnCount < 1024));
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < keyReg.size(); i++)
        {
            if (keyReg[i] == 1)
            {
                m = m + int(pow(2, i));
            }
            n = p * q;
            f = (p - 1) * (q - 1);
            for (int k = 0; end < 1; k++)
            {
                if ((1 + k * f) % d == 0)
                {
                    end = 2;
                    e = (1 + (k * f)) / d;
                }
            }
            g = int(pow(m, e));
            c = g % n;
            return (c);
        }
    };

    lfsr() // Constructor
    {
        y = 0;
        turnCount = 0;
        xx = 0;
        polyLoc = 320;
        n = 0;
        end = 0;
        p = 0;
        q = 0;
        d = 0;
        f = 0;
        e = 0;
        m = 0;
        c = 0;
        l = 0, g = 0;
        boost::dynamic_bitset<> inpSeq(5);
        boost::dynamic_bitset<> operSeq(5);
        boost::dynamic_bitset<> bit(5);
    }

    void rsa(int x, int y, int z, boost::dynamic_bitset<> initSeq)
    {
        p = x;
        q = y;
        d = z;
        inpSeq = initSeq;
    }

    int main()
    {
        lfsr public_key, private_key;
        public_key.rsa(29, 41, 74, 00111);
        private_key.rsa(43, 89, 73, 01011);
        cout << "Public key is: " << public_key.key() << endl;
        cout << "Private key is: " << private_key.key() << endl;
        cin.get();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: 18 parameter constructor? You win!

Comment: How do you work with this code indentation?

Comment: @awesomeyi Crosseyed.

Comment: Well what @CaptainObvlious tried to say is you might want to consider something like a `struct` or an `array` because these are really `a lot` of parameters for one constructor .. By the way: Your code is not helpful. Shorten it and post the compiler error.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I am a novice coder with a coding timed-challenge.

Comment: You have unbalanced { and }...

Comment: I don't see a default constructor, I doubt this even compiles.

Comment: @RetiredNinja It doesn't, a lot of errors show up when trying to compile.

Comment: I don't see `lfsr` in the definition of `rsa`. You should post the version you have a question about, not the version without the error.

Comment: You have an infinite loop on `while ((operSeq != inpSeq) && (turnCount < 1024));`.

Comment: @Barmer Sorry for missing up that. The version with lsfr in definition of rsa doesn't produce the error I am talking about, now it doesn't.

Comment: gcc 2.8.2? First version of gcc I used was 2.9 something - and that was more than 20 years ago... You probably mean 4.8.2, but could be 3.8.2, 4.7.2 or any other random number sequence...

Comment: In the currently posted code the missing `}` in the class definition throws everything off.  You can't implement `lfsr::lfsr` because you're still inside the class declaration where the qualifier would not be necessary.  This looks like a question about a typo.

Comment: How is so? After 'return (c);}' there is }; for closing the class.

Comment: Nope, after that return there is a closing brace for the for loop and a closing brace for the function, but there's one missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude. Perhaps you should consider making use of named parameters.

*What is the "Named Parameter Idiom"*
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/named-parameter-idiom.html

Or if you use Boost, consider using the following.

*The Boost Parameter Library*
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html

Or, if you do not like that, a single parameter that is a map of a string to a union (or any, also part of Boost).

All of these would be a better alternative to a constructor with 18 parameters.

Besides, your declared lfsr constructor with 18 parameters, does not match your defined lfsr constructor, with 0, parameters.

By declared, I mean the statement that a function exists, witout code.

lfsr(int, int, int, int, int, int, int,
         int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int,
         boost::dynamic_bitset<>, boost::dynamic_bitset<>, boost::dynamic_bitset<>);

Is your declared constructor.

By defined, I mean the code.

lfsr()

Is your defined constructor. Of course it should be lfsr::lfsr().

void rsa(int x, int y, int z, boost::dynamic_bitset<> initSeq)

Should be as follows.

void lfsr::rsa(int x, int y, int z, boost::dynamic_bitset<> initSeq)

These clues should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks, the meaning of declaration and definition are known to me, but I think the complete knowledge of classes nature isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class lfsr {
   // Constructor declaration
   lfsr();
};

// Constructor definition
lfsr::lfsr() {

}
```

**And** I think you are missing a `}` *before* your class terminal `};`.

Comment: I really need to know what is wrong with initializing many variables with the constructor?

Comment: There is nothing "*wrong*" in particular if it compiles and works but it is not considered as a good coding style. `struct`s and `class`es are there for you to encapsulate data in an organized way and a ctor with so many paramaters might indicate that you didn't do that properly. Maybe if you'd give your parameters some names like `MyConstructor(int xCoordinate, int yCoordinate)` I could tell you more bot not if you do it like `MyConstructor(int,int)`

Answer (score 1):

You should move the whole `lfsr()` into `class lfsr`, or declare `lfsr();` inside `class lfsr` before implementing it as

```
lfsr::lfsr()
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: But I will have a 15 arguments constructor that way two, don't I? I don't know how using struct will help here, it was mentioned above by @Stefan R. Falk.

Comment: This isn't my answer but well.. I can not tell what is best for your code because I don't know exactly what you're doing with all those parameters. But in general: Always try to write slim constructors and don't use them as common functions or methods. Also try to think in objects and *sometimes* in structs and think about how you can systematically declare members for your objects and structs.

Comment: @ Stefan R. Falk, If I used a function to assign initial values to this large number of integers, why will be that different from doing that using the constructor?